# Spring REST and Push notifications

Tags: spring, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push, spring-rest

I'm very new to push notifications. I have to send push notifications to mobile devices using Spring Rest services...

Found that through APNS we can connect IOS devices. Any samples or any beginner tutorial to connect SPRING REST with APNS? what about android devices how to send push notifications to android devices?

Answer (score 1):

To send PUSH notifications to android devices use GCM/FCM based and for Iphone APNS based.

Start with Google Developers Console and get sender ID and device token... 
now follow below URL

http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/